# How to send json using faraday

Tags: ruby, linode, faraday

I need to consume the linode api, in the description it says I have to send the data using curl like this

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -X POST -d '{
        "label": "asdfasdf"
        "ssh_key": "asdfasdf"
    }' \
    https://api.linode.com/v4/profile/sshkeys
```

I tried using

```rb
http = Faraday::Connection.new 'https://api.linode.com/v4/profile/sshkeys'
http.authorization :Bearer, token
http.post('', { 'label' => 'adfadf', ..}.to_json)
```

But every request it says label and ssh_key required. I don´t know how to send this particular request

anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the content-type as json in the header, if you're sending a json data.

```
http.post(
  '',
  { 'label' => 'adfadf', ..}.to_json,
  { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
)
```

Reference: https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/usage/